# PHP: Filter all codes except scripts and images from MY site?

Tags: php, regex

Lets say a member left a comment.

```
Hi! Look at these cars.
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/possiblefolder/possiblesub/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://othersite.com/possiblefolder/possiblesub/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://www.mysite.otherside.com/possiblefolder/image.jpg"></img>
Which is your favorite?
```

I want the results to come up as:

```
Hi! Look at these cars.
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/possiblefolder/possiblesub/image.jpg"></img>
http://othersite.com/possiblefolder/possiblesub/image.jpg  
http://www.mysite.otherside.com/possiblefolder/possiblesub/image.jpg  
Which is your favorite?
```

I want to filter all codes except images and scripts coming from my site. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: whats up with that `<img ..` on the first ? do you want first as `<img` and rest as src only.

Comment: I want `<img ...` to stay for my site's images because I know they're safe to show. I want my images to be displayed, while other sites images to be displayed as links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
<(\w+).+src=[\x22|'](?![^\x22']+mysite\.com[^\x22']+)([^\x22']+)[\x22|'].*>(?:</\1>)?
```

Group 1 is the tag used and group 2 is the "src" value so you can do a replace.

[In Browser Demo](http://regexr.com?2tdbm)

[image]

Comment: Absolutely BEAUTIFUL! Thank you!

Comment: I'm having some issues, it looked like it worked on your site but once I tried it in php it didn't work.

Comment: preg_replace(<(\w+).+src=[\x22|'](?![^\x22']+mysite\.com[^\x22']+)([^\x22']+)[\x22|'].*>(?:</\1>)?
, $2, $message); should work right? But it's not, is it working for you maybe?

Comment: Try preg_replace("/<(\w+).+src=[\x22|'](?![^\x22']+mysite\.com[^\x22']+)([^\x22']+)[\x­22|'].*>(?:</\1>)?/igm", '$2', $message) notice the ignoreCase, global, and multiline flags.

Answer (score 1):

In most reasonable cases and in particular in your examples, this will work:

```
$new_comment = preg_replace('%<img.*?\ssrc="(http://(?!www.mysite.com).*?)".*?>.*?</img>%', '\1', $old_comment);
```

It will give the result you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not proper XHTML, run it through Tidy. If it's already clean XHTML, skip this part

```
$config = array('output-xhtml'   => true);
$tidy = new tidy();
$html = $tidy->repareString($html, $config, 'utf8');
```

Now, having clean XHTML you can use XPath:

```
$xhtml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
foreach ($xhtml->xpath('//*/img') as $img_parent) {
   if(!(strpos($img_parent->img->src, 'http://www.mysite.com/') === 0)) {
     $img_parent->img = new SimpleXMLElement($img_parent->img->src);
   }
}
$cleaned_html = $xhtml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP strip_tags() to strip all HTML tags out from user-comment (highly recommended), also you need to implement some script code such as BBCode on PHPbb forums, etc...

```
[img]possibleimgdir/someimage.jpg[/img]
```

later search for [img] and [/img], append your root URL in front of content found between tags (example. http://www.mysite.com/possibleimgdir/someimage.jpg), check if file exists and then create HTML IMG tags for that SRC property if it is valid...

That's just one of possible ideas!

Comment: Thought about this method, but I wanted to stick to using <img codes so people could copy and paste a code onto other sites.

Comment: I did not realize that you want to filter out code people copied from clipboard. Well then, I suggest preg_replace()...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a jQuery oneliner:

```
$('img:not(src^="http://www.mysite.com/")').hide()
```